# Get notes using json read in tumblr read

Tags: json, tumblr

In tumblr,Is there any way to get the notes using below url with custom theme page, i have check lots of blog not able to get notes or notes count

> http://{name}.tumblr.com/api/read/json

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like version 1 of the Tumblr API supports notes. However version 2 does:

`http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{name}.tumblr.com/posts/text?notes_info=true`

**Reference**

- Tumblr API v1: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v1
- Tumblr API v2: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts